# How to reference phone file structure

Tags: android, nfc

I am practicing with the code in this tutorial: [NFC Beam Tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/beam-files/send-files.html)

In this section: ( Titled: Specify the files to send )

```
     /* Create a list of URIs, get a File,
      * and set its permissions
      */
    private Uri[] mFileUris = new Uri[10];
    String transferFile = "transferimage.jpg";
    File extDir = getExternalFilesDir(null);
    File requestFile = new File(extDir, transferFile);
    requestFile.setReadable(true, false);
    // Get a URI for the File and add it to the list of URIs
    fileUri = Uri.fromFile(requestFile);
    if (fileUri != null) {
        mFileUris[0] = fileUri;
    } else {
        Log.e("My Activity", "No File URI available for file.");
    }
```

I wonder if I can refer to files on the phone; files in the Music or Photo directory. Is this possible, and how?

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a [Content Provider](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-basics.html). For music files for instance you can query for [MediaStore.Audio.Media](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Audio.Media.html)-data to get the Uri for all songs on the sd card.